# Unable to record checkbox in load runner 12.5

Tags: loadrunner

I am new to HP Load Runner. I am using using Load Runner 12.5 to test a web application.

**While recording using HTTP protocol:**

I click **Register** link

There is a checkbox "I accept". I selected the checkbox.

**When I view my script:**

I see the register link step generated.

But script did not generate the checkbox step.

As for recording options, I tried All the options under General > Recording: HTML and URL.

[image]

When I inspected the checkbox in chrome, I see the below code:

```
<div class="form-group checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="TermsAndConditionsAccepted" value="True" id="TermsAndConditionsAccepted" data-val-truerequired="You must accept the.." data-val-required="The TermsAndConditionsAccepted field is required." data-val-required-allowempty="false" data-val="true">
                            <label class="control-label" for="TermsAndConditionsAccepted">I agree to the above Terms and Conditions</label>
                            <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="TermsAndConditions" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
```

Load runner generated the below script. As you can see register link is the last step but I do not see checkbox step. Please advise on how I can fix it.

```
web_url("example.com", 
    "URL=example.com/", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    );

lr_think_time(15);

web_link("Register", 
    "Text=Register", 
    "Snapshot=t2.inf", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=../signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22usersessionhub%22%7D%5D&_=1500044401633", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);


return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at Architecture.  You are recording at an HTTP transport layer level.  If your click to confirm dialog is purely a client side event, perhaps presented via JavaScript, then you should not expect to see any server side communication.

If you insist that you absolutely must see this in your test code and this is a 100% client side generated event, then may I suggest TruClient, GUI, Citrix or RDP is your path to a solution.